# Sd card formating process failled as had been mistakly unplugged

Tags: sd-card

Hello Ubuntu community I was trying to format my SD card so that it would be usable in any device. As I did so the windows disappeared and nothing to acknowledge if the process was already done or not. So I unplugged the SD card and an error came out stating something like the formatting process has failed. I tried to reboot the system with the SD card in but still no sign of life. What can I do to have that SD card back to life? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

1. insert the sd card and then open disks application from here:

[image: as shown in this image] then

2. select your sdcard and press ctrl+f :

[image: as shown here] 
by pressing ctrl+f your sd card gets formatted.

3. after formatting then go to edit partition option and create a new partition for your sd card. then you are done.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once.

Eject and reinsert the SD card, then try to format it again. If your file browser doesn't find it, try formatting it in GParted.

That worked for me, but I'm not sure if it's reproducible.

Comment: Please tell me more about that GParted.

Comment: GParted is a FOSS formatting utility which is in standard Ubuntu repositories, and probably installed on your machine. It requires sudo and a lot of caution  (you can wipe /dev/sda without care) but it can fix all partitioning and formatting issues.