# Error while formatting an SD card with GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, sd-card

I'm trying to format an SD card to then install a booting image (i want to make a ZedBoard boot on Linux with the SD card). I'm following a tutorial to use Gparted. I precise that I'm using Ubuntu on Virtualbox on a Windows 10 host.

The SD card i try to format already includes 2 partitions which i would like to delete then replace with 2 others partitions. But there are some problems.

First, when i Unmount then Delete the 2 existing partitions and then "Apply all operations", the 2 partitions seem to disappear (replaced with an unallocated partition). But after a short loading, the 2 previous partitions which i tried to delete come back like nothing happened.

Second, if I try to create the new partitions after deleting the previous ones (before "Apply all operations) and then apply all operations, i got these error messages : "Can't have overlapping partitions" and "Partition(s) 3 on /dev/sdb have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the changes, probably because it/they are in use. As a result the old partitions will remain in use. You should reboot now before making further changes."
I precise that the two partitions i want to create are in Fat32 and ext4.

The full error report is available here:

[image: error report]

Answer (score 0):

i am referring you my previous answer related to problem above, please follow the steps and your problem will be solved.

[best way to getback your sdcard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747702/sd-card-formating-process-failled-as-had-been-mistakly-unplugged/747730#747730)