# Cannot read or write to SD card

Tags: mount, sd-card

I'm trying to read my SD cards. They worked fine several times, I wrote some data onto them, then I used them on my cell phone. After that I tried opening them on somebody else's Windows but it wouldn't see them. I came home and tried opening them on my Ubuntu but it says:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/yuha/3161-3131: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/yuha/3161-3131"' exited with non-zero exit status 2:
stdout: `FUSE exfat 1.0.1
'
stderr: `BUG: failed to read 512 bytes from file at 0.
```

I tried searching for an answer with this "non-zero exit status 2" but everyone else seems to have status 32.

What can I do to fix this? I don't need the data on SD cards, I just want to be able to use them again. I wanted to format them but it says `device not found`. How can I reach the cards and format them or otherwise return them to normal state?

Upon trying to check the integrity it gave this:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  97.7G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 138.8G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 244.1G  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0 687.4G  0 part /media/data
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 11 20:25 ata-MATSHITABD-CMB_UJ160_WR39_009484 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 11 20:25 ata-TOSHIBA_THNSNJ256GMCU_34NS101OT4ZW -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 11 20:25 ata-TOSHIBA_THNSNJ256GMCU_34NS101OT4ZW-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 11 20:25 ata-TOSHIBA_THNSNJ256GMCU_34NS101OT4ZW-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 11 20:25 ata-TOSHIBA_THNSNJ256GMCU_34NS101OT4ZW-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 11 20:25 ata-TOSHIBA_THNSNJ256GMCU_34NS101OT4ZW-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 11 20:25 ata-WDC_WD10EZEX-21M2NA0_WCC3F5RZDVUH -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 11 20:25 ata-WDC_WD10EZEX-21M2NA0_WCC3F5RZDVUH-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 11 20:25 ata-WDC_WD10EZEX-21M2NA0_WCC3F5RZDVUH-part2 -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 14 12:14 usb-Mass_Storage_Device_121220160204-0:0 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 11 20:25 wwn-0x500080d9100e53ba -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 11 20:25 wwn-0x500080d9100e53ba-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 11 20:25 wwn-0x500080d9100e53ba-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 11 20:25 wwn-0x500080d9100e53ba-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 11 20:25 wwn-0x500080d9100e53ba-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 11 20:25 wwn-0x50014ee26056824c -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 11 20:25 wwn-0x50014ee26056824c-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 11 20:25 wwn-0x50014ee26056824c-part2 -> ../../sdb2
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/null count=1
[sudo] password for yuha: 
dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sdc’: No medium found
```

So it cannot see the sdc upon lsblk command but can see it upon the other one. However, it says "no medium" if I try to access it.
I tried dmesg, it gave a lot of information, I am pasting some here:

```
[211738.615775] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[211738.616627] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[211739.010981] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] 123992064 512-byte logical blocks: (63.4 GB/59.1 GiB)
[211739.011231] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[211739.011241] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[211739.011482] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[211739.011492] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[211739.014185]  sdc: sdc1
[211739.015282] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[211743.676940] sdc: detected capacity change from 63483936768 to 0
[211768.444125] usb 3-10: USB disconnect, device number 8
[211771.434907] usb 3-8: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[211771.564119] usb 3-8: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=1212
[211771.564127] usb 3-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[211771.564131] usb 3-8: Product: Mass Storage Device
[211771.564134] usb 3-8: Manufacturer: Generic
[211771.564137] usb 3-8: SerialNumber: 121220160204
[211771.564800] usb-storage 3-8:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[211771.565089] scsi11 : usb-storage 3-8:1.0
[211772.563279] scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[211772.563936] sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[211772.958456] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] 123992064 512-byte logical blocks: (63.4 GB/59.1 GiB)
[214266.173071] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 4104
[214266.173071] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 4105
[214266.173461] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[214266.173463] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[214266.173464] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[214266.173465] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[214266.173466] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[214266.173467] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[214266.173468] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[214266.173468] Read(10): 28 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 00
[214266.173471] end_request: critical medium error, dev sdc, sector 65536
[214266.254724] sdc: detected capacity change from 127865454592 to 0
[214312.436215] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Comment: Post the output of `fdisk -l` to your question. Maybe also `dmesg`.

Comment: Have you installed exfat support? Ubuntu doesn't support exfat by default.

Comment: The error message points to a low-level I/O error. Possible duplicate of [How do I check the integrity of a storage medium (hard disk or flash drive)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539184/how-do-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-storage-medium-hard-disk-or-flash-drive) If the integrity verification of the storage medium itself succeeds please report back so we can investigate other options.

Comment: Just simply follow the steps in this answer [https://askubuntu.com/questions/747702/sd-card-formating-process-failled-as-had-been-mistakly-unplugged/747730#747730]

Comment: Akhil Varma, I tried disks and it can "see" it (it is there, mass storage device) but it won't let me format! Nothing on ctrl+f, and the format button in the menu is gray!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. The reason was faulty micro SD adapter. I was using a USB SD adapter with a micro SD adapter (a set). Turns out, the micro SD adapter was broken. As a result, Ubuntu was "seeing" the USB but could not reach the storage medium attached to it because the micro adapter wouldn't allow it. Naturally, the machine was reporting what it was seeing: mass storage device inserted but no medium.

I changed the micro sd adapter and all 3 cards are normally functioning now.